# How to assign field value of a collection document to another collection document field as a value in Firestore using java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 collections; BookingInformation and ParkingArea. From the ParkingArea document, I want to save the latest value of the "areanumber" field to the BookingInformation collection with the field name "Area".

I have tried the following. In logcat, I can view the required data but no clue how to assign it. I didn't find any resources. Please help.

```
final List<String> parkingDocList = new ArrayList<>();

dataStore.collection("ParkingArea").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                parkingDocList.add(documentSnapshot.getId());
            }
        } 
    }
});

final Map<String, Object> reserveInfo = new HashMap<>();

reserveInfo.put("date", date.getText().toString());
reserveInfo.put("startTime", startTime.getText().toString());
reserveInfo.put("endTime", endTime.getText().toString());
reserveInfo.put("userId", currentUserId);
reserveInfo.put("area", allocatedArea[0]);

dataStore.collection("BookingInformation").document(id).set(reserveInfo)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Toast toast4 =
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Area reserved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast4.show();
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast toast5 = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Reservation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast5.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firestore (and most cloud APIs) asynchronously. This means that any code that needs the data from the database, must be **inside** the `onComplete` handler that is called when the data is loaded.

So in your case:

```
final List<String> parkingDocList = new ArrayList<>();

dataStore.collection("ParkingArea").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                parkingDocList.add(documentSnapshot.getId());
            }

            final Map<String, Object> reserveInfo = new HashMap<>();

            reserveInfo.put("date", date.getText().toString());
            reserveInfo.put("startTime", startTime.getText().toString());
            reserveInfo.put("endTime", endTime.getText().toString());
            reserveInfo.put("userId", currentUserId);
            reserveInfo.put("area", allocatedArea[0]);

            dataStore.collection("BookingInformation").document(id).set(reserveInfo)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast toast4 =
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Area reserved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast4.show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast toast5 = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Reservation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast5.show();
                    }
                });
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh okay. It worked. Thank you so much.